# ArcGIS Field with greek characters lost on export

Tags: encoding, gis, qgis, arcmap, regional-settings

I have a shapefile that has a field that is string(12) and some rows contain 2 greek characters.
When I open the shapefile in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro and select export data, all the rows that contain the greek characters, become 10 characters (ex, if I had 98765AE43210, on export, becomes 98765AE43-lose last 2 characters).

I already done the following;

I open the shapefile in QGIS, and the field in properties has datatype text(14).

I create a new field in ArcMap / ArcGIS Pro / QGis with datatype string(12) and in ESRI products get 10 characters and in QGIS, 14 characters!

If you import the shapefile in a file geodatabase, as a feature dataset, all working right, until the export from the feature dataset to shapefile, where again we have 10 characters.

Any Ideas on how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean `Α` (U+0391,  *Greek Capital Letter Alpha*)
and `Ε` (U+0395,  *Greek Capital Letter Epsilon*) instead of  `A` (U+0041,  *Latin Capital Letter A*) and `E` (U+0045,  *Latin Capital Letter E*)?

Comment: One solution is http://switchfromshapefile.org/